# Interpreting gcc warning/error messages split across multiple lines

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

The gcc/g++ compiler (gcc 4.9.2) outputs error messages across multiple lines and *sometimes* multiple consecutive lines should be read together as one, in order to get all the details and the fullest explanation about the error.

My question is, how do you tell when multiple error lines should be read together as one, and when a given error line is to be read all by itself?

In other words, when is an error message continued by the next error message and when is it just a single one line independent error message?

Here is an example of a program I wrote that deliberately fails to compile in a way that I understand and I know that the multi-line error messages are all part of one message and are specifically telling me one thing:

The code:

```
  1   #include <iostream>
  2   
  3   
  4   using std::cout;
  5   using std::endl;
  6   
  7   class MyClass
  8   {
  9       public:
 10           // Not OK because a gets initialised before b
 11           // See warning in gcc output
 12           MyClass(int x) : b(x), a(b-1), c(0)
 13           { cout << "a=" << a
 14               << "\nb=" << b
 15                << "\nc=" << c << "\n"; 
 16           };
 17   
 18       private:
 19           int a;
 20           int b;
 21           int c;
 22   };
```

The output of compilation:

```
user@computer:$ make proggy  

g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wall -Werror    proggy.cpp   -o proggy
proggy.cpp: In constructor ‘MyClass::MyClass(int)’:
proggy.cpp:20:13: error: ‘MyClass::b’ will be initialized after [-Werror=reorder]
         int b;
             ^
proggy.cpp:19:13: error:   ‘int MyClass::a’ [-Werror=reorder]
         int a;
             ^
proggy.cpp:12:9: error:   when initialized here [-Werror=reorder]
         MyClass(int x) : b(x), a(b-1), c(0)
         ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
<builtin>: recipe for target 'proggy' failed
make: *** [proggy] Error 1
```

Notice that the full message for the single issue (which is that the order of usage doesn't match the order of initialisation) is actually split over THREE error message lines.

The first error message says:

```
proggy.cpp:20:13: error: ‘MyClass::b’ will be initialized after
```

which clearly is a sentence that hasn't been finished.  It needs to have the next two error messages appended to it. And if I were to read just the second error message in isolation, that would make no sense:

```
 proggy.cpp:19:13: error:   ‘int MyClass::a’ [-Werror=reorder]
             int a;
```

So, I need to merge all these messages into one and form a single sentence stating what the problem is. That sentence would be this:

```
    "‘MyClass::b’ will be initialized after ‘MyClass::a’ when initialized
   here (line 12) --> MyClass(int x) : b(x), a(b-1), c(0)"
```

That is obvious in this example because this a small example and I understand what is going on in the code. But if I have a more lengthy error message output, how do I know when to read a number of consecutive error messages as one?

How do I know when a given error message is to be continued by the next error message and when it is not?

Comment: Reading error messages is kind of an art.  It takes some getting used to and different compilers use different language and or formatting to describe the same error.  Generally I just look at the first 3-4 messages and try and fix what they are telling me.  Then I compile again and see if I succeeded or not.  This is useful as the first error could cause a lot of other errors that will disappear once you fix it.

Comment: I usually dont rely on the error message to know what the error really is. Most of the time it is much easier to look directly at the code to see what is wrong. Btw when you use templates a single error can span hundreds of lines and you have no other chance than reading only the first 1-2 lines and then inspect the code to find the mistake

Comment: If you use tool from clang, you may launch compilation programmatically and have class as error which you should be able to handle easier.